# Optional Parameter in function by inference

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, type-inference

I want to use infer("post") without the second parameter as the Data object is empty. But the inference must still require a second parameter if the Data object is not empty.

Note: notice that the checker to see if the Data object is empty is "keyof Data extends never".

```js
type MappedData = {
  user: {
    name: string;
  };
  post: {};
};

function infer\<Key extends keyof MappedData, Data extends MappedData\[Key\]\>(
  key: Key,
  data: keyof Data extends never ? undefined : Data
) {}

infer("user", { name: "Ryan" });

infer("post", undefined);

infer("post"); // Expected 2 arguments, but got 1
```

See that with a single parameter, an object, it is possible to infer to make the "params" property unknown. How to do something like this?

```js
type ExtractData<
  Key extends keyof MappedData,
  Data extends MappedData[Key] = MappedData[Key]
> = keyof Data extends never
  ? {
      key: Key;
    }
  : {
      key: Key;
      params: Data;
    };

function infer2<Key extends keyof MappedData>(o: ExtractData<Key>) {}

infer2({
  key: "user",
  params: { name: "Ryan" },
});

infer2({
  key: "post",
  params: {}, // Argument of type '{ key: "post"; params: {}; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: "post"; }'.
});

infer2({
  key: "post",
});
```

Comment: You can destructure a conditional type that results in tuples as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m3BDkN).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXvxJm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (edit: quite similar to @pink's approach; I'll defer to them if they prefer to write the answer here)

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot.
I was doing just that, but I didn't know it was possible to name indexes of an array type.